# convert value in timedata

Tags: r, datetime, time

I´m relative new to R and right now I´m struggling with converting my time data.

I have a list of values, which should be daily data (01/012007-31/12/2015)

```
str(timedata)
num [1:3103(1d)] 733043 733044 733045 733046 733047 ...
```

I would like to read the daily dates 01/01/07 02/01/07....

I tried to convert it with the function

```
as.POSIXct(timedata, origin = "2007-01-01", tz = "GMT")
```

but the result is wrong:

```
"2007-01-09 11:39:08 GMT" "2007-01-09 11:39:09 GMT" "2007-01-09 11:39:10 GMT" 
"2007-01-09 11:39:11 GMT" "2007-01-09 11:39:12 GMT"...
```

maybe someone could help me?! I guess it should be possible to get my dates, but which function makes sense?

Comment: Can you write down the result you need to obtain under the result you actually obtain? ty! :)

Comment: POSIXct times are encoded in seconds. You probably want `as.Date`. Voting to close as typo. (to get the format you expect, dd/mm/yyyy, please read `?strptime`

Comment: @Ale I hope I understood you right. The result I need to obtain is a daily time series from 01/01/2007 to 31/21/2015

Comment: @42 ifs try to work with strptime I always get NA results.

Answer (score 0):

This gives a daily vector of dates from Jan 1,  2007 to Dec 31, 2015:

```
 tsD <- seq.Date("2007-01-01", "2015-12-31")
```

You could also coerce that vector to Dates. But to do so you need to use the correct origin for your data which appears to be the erroneous starting date chosen by the Lotus 1-2-3 developers and perpetuated by Microsoft:

```
 tsD <- as.Date(my.timedata, origin="0000-01-01")
```

I actually don't know how to do that is one step. So I would be subtracting 1 from those values to get a corrected date series. Read `?as.Date`

```
> tsD
[1] "2007-01-02" "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-06"
```

If you want the dates to be displayed as 'dd/mm/yyyy' you need to read about formatting strings in `?strptime` but use the generic `format` function which has a Date method:

```
> format(tsD, format="%d-%m-%Y")
[1] "02-01-2007" "03-01-2007" "04-01-2007" "05-01-2007" "06-01-2007"
```